# Using arcpy to export map with XY Event Source

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to create an arcpy script that will export a map without having to open arcmap. My map consists of a shape file for the counties in California and points from a XY Event Source which is linked to an access database .accdb. Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy.mapping
arcpy.OverWriteOutput = 1
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Path to .mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToEMF(mxd,"Path to .emf")
```

This will output a map with counties and labels but not the points linked to the database. If I type this directly into arcmap it exports the map with the points showing. I have done lots of searching and cannot figure out how to get them to show without exporting the points to a shapefile first which won't work because the points are updated regularly. Any help would be great.

Comment: Would you consider expanding the script so it first exports the points to a shapefile, and then exports the EMF? (I realize just exporting is much more ideal, I'm just thinking about a workaround in case it's not possible.)

Comment: Sure although I am fairly new at scripting in python and for arcgis. How would I go about doing that?